# Converting float list to byte-like object results in a corrupted image

Tags: python, png, packing, ieee, pyvisa

I am trying to convert data from a Keysight scope to `.png` Image.
When I looked how to do it online, I stumbled the following code:

```
# Download the screen image.
# --------------------------------------------------------
sDisplay = do_query_ieee_block(":DISPlay:DATA? PNG")
# Save display data values to file.
f = open("screen_image.png", "wb")
f.write(sDisplay)
f.close()
```

The problem with code above is that I'm not sure what `do_query_ieee_block` is. I thought it was under `pyvisa` but couldn't find it there. After looking online, I understood that `query_binary_values` is more or less the same thing as `pyvisa` assumes that data is in `IEEE`.

According to this information, I wrote the following code:

```
import pyvisa
import struct

IDN="SomeScopeIDN" #something like 'USB0::0xhhhh::0xhhhh::MYdddddddd::0::INSTR' 
scope=pyvisa.ResourceManager().open_resource(IDN)
binImage=self.scope.query_binary_values(":DISPlay:DATA? PNG") #This gets a list of floats
byteImage=struct.pack('%sf' % len(binImage),*binImage) #Convert the list to bytes-like object
path=r"c:\Users\user\Desktop\Scope_Image.png"
with open (path,'wb') as f:
  f.write(byteImage)
```

This creates an image, but the outcome is bad:

[image: Corrupted Image]

and from snipping tool:

[image: Corrupted Image]

As you can see, only the upper 10% of the image is fine but the rest is not (it will be mentioned that each time I retrieve new data from the scope I get a different area that is corrupted, which is between 50-90% of the picture. Most of the time the corrupted area is between 80-90%, as seen in the picture above).

So basically my questions are:

1. Could it be that I don't read the whole data from the instrument? and if so, how can overcome this issue?
2. Could it be happening because of packing in a wrong way? If so, what's the solution?

Comment: What is the result of the first code snippet?

Comment: What does the manual of the Keysight scope say about the `:DISPlay:DATA? PNG` command? Are you sure that it returns a list of *floats* and not a list of *integers*, or simply the binary data of the PNG image which you do not need to convert in any way before writing it to a file?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I can't get the results of the first code as I don't have IEEE attribute.. The manual says it's fine. The output from binImage is float numbers (for example binImage[5] is -2.6164308388710655e+33...). I tried to save the binary data as it is into PNG, but it says that it requires a byte-like object and not a list, hence the convertation

Answer (score 0):

Seen an example that may be helpful:

1. Add `datatype='B', container=bytearray` as arguments to `query_binary_values()`
2. Try `':DISP:DATA? ON,OFF,PNG'` interchangeably

```
import pyvisa

IDN="SomeScopeIDN" #something like 'USB0::0xhhhh::0xhhhh::MYdddddddd::0::INSTR' 
scope=pyvisa.ResourceManager().open_resource(IDN)
binImage=self.scope.query_binary_values(":DISPlay:DATA? PNG", datatype='B', container=bytearray)
path=r"c:\Users\user\Desktop\Scope_Image.png"
with open (path,'wb') as f:
  f.write(byteImage)
```

Comment: Why do you mean by that? You used the `do_query_ieee_block` in the code of the question. Do you mean something else or am I missing something?

Comment: look at the the question again... I got the code somewhere online but Pyvisa don't have this attribute, only query_binary, but the conversation results in a corrupted image..

You can see my code below the one you mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using `query_binary_values()`, only instead of trying to generate a png I was trying to read back ARB waveforms.

The solution I found related to the endianess of my data. Look into the `is_big_endian` parameter to see if that may be causing the issue. I would also look into the `header_fmt`, `delay`, and `chunk_size` parameters.

https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.MessageBasedResource.query_binary_values